# DataGrid doing unwanted rearranging

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am having trouble with the WPF `DataGrid` rearranging my rows when I do not want it to.

Steps:

1. Apply grouping
2. Sort the `DataGrid` by a column with duplicates within the group
3. Change a cell not in the sorted column
4. Observe that the rows reorder moving the edited row to the bottom of the set of rows that have matching values in their sorted column

Example (Note the sorting by LastName):

```
FirstName | LastName ^ | Amount
----------+------------+---------
Group:Flinstone
Fred      | Flinstone  | 42
Wilma     | Flinstone  | 22
Pebbles   | Flinstone  | 28
Dino      | Flinstone  | 64
```

Changing Wilma's amount from 22 to 18 will result in the DataGrid rearranging as follows:

```
FirstName | LastName ^ | Amount
----------+------------+---------
Group:Flinstone
Fred      | Flinstone  | 42
Pebbles   | Flinstone  | 28
Dino      | Flinstone  | 64
Wilma     | Flinstone  | 18
```

How do I stop the `DataGrid` from rearranging the rows like this?

Note: The unwanted reordering does not happen if the `DataGrid` does not have any grouping applied to it.

Here is the code I am using:

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public ListCollectionView ItemsView { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        Items.Add(new Item("Fred", "Flinstone", 42));
        Items.Add(new Item("Wilma", "Flinstone", 22));
        Items.Add(new Item("Pebbles", "Flinstone", 52));
        Items.Add(new Item("Dino", "Flinstone", 52));
        Items.Add(new Item("Barney", "Rubble", 32));
        Items.Add(new Item("Betty", "Rubble", 62));
        Items.Add(new Item("BamBam", "Rubble", 42));
        Items.Add(new Item("George", "Jetson", 22));
        Items.Add(new Item("Jane", "Jetson", 52));
        Items.Add(new Item("Judy", "Jetson", 32));
        Items.Add(new Item("Elroy", "Jetson", 62));
        Items.Add(new Item("Astro", "Jetson", 42));

        ItemsView = new ListCollectionView(Items);
        ItemsView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("LastName"));
    }
}
```

View:

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}">
    <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public Item(string firstName, string lastName, decimal amount)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        Amount = amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you make the change (of wilma's amount from 22 to 18) ?

Comment: @DrDev I change Wilma's amount through the UI, not in code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the nicest solution, but in the past I have circumvented this problem by sorting the data in my data source, and not in the DataGridView. I learned how to do this from [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/91d65e58-60b3-4367-a580-07cdf7574eb3/datagridview-suppressing-autosort-resort). (I always bookmark useful coding tips)

I hope this is what you were looking for!

EDIT: The second to last post at the bottom is the one that actually works.

Comment: Can you please summarize the solution found in the link? Links are very helpful when looking for additional information, but [on their own they are not good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/189763).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default sort behavior of specific columns (even when column headers are clicked) using attached properties, which should address your problem. With this solution, clicking a header will apply your custom sort order, which should remain 'active' regardless of any underlying data changes.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218963/2115261